# How do I shutdown the computer automatically, after bot finishes running from terminal?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

I would like to know how can I schedule a shutdown in my computer after a bot finishes running totally.

I'm running a instagram bot from my own residential network. It is configured in a way that after all the tasks are done it simply stops running.

And I would like my computer to shutdown after the bot stops running in order to save energy. For example, when the bot is done something like 'Session Ended' shows up on terminal. I would like the computer to shutdown after this.

I've seen questions related to this, but they were according to a torrent or something, and the computer would shutdown after the download is completed.

In this case it's simply something that is running in the terminal and I want the computer to shutdown when that task is totally done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this: first, find the PID (process ID) of the running process, using `pgrep [name of script, or program]`.

Then write another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ps -p $PID; do sleep 1; done ; shutdown -h
```

Replace $PID by the actual process ID.
What the script does is: look if the process with the ID still exists. If so, sleep a second and look again. If not, proceed to shut down the system

Save it (as `myscript.sh`, say), make it executable (`chmod +x myscript.sh`) and run it with root permission: `sudo myscript.sh`. You need root permission to do the `shutdown` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand what you say, but when I try this: pgrep [name of script, or program] , the terminal shows a huge list of numbers from 1 to 5115, one in each line... How do I know which one corresponds to the PID that we're trying to find? Thank you once again!

Comment: If your bot executable is called `mybot` , then `pgrep mybot` should output just one line, or perhaps a few if it uses child processes.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I run the bot from a file called mybot.py , it is not executable, can I still find the process id? Thank you

Comment: Sure: just do `ps -ef | grep mybot.py`. The first number is the PID.

Comment: Thanks! I got 3 lines:
3520  1634  1 11:55 ?        00:00:07 gedit /home/dpascoa/Desktop/instapy-quickstart-master/test.py
3792  3551  0 12:05 pts/0    00:00:00 python3 test.py
3965  3956  0 12:06 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto test.py
Which one is the right one?

Comment: The middle one. The first tells me you are editing the Python program in `gedit`. The third one is the `grep` command which always shows itself. The second one is what you need, its PID is 3792.

Answer (score 2):

Just append `shutdown` to the command with the `&&` operator. `&&` would make sure the system shuts down only if the command exits succesfully. So you need to run

```
your-command && shutdown
```

Comment: Great! I've not wondered that! You mean simply putting all the lines of the code inside (), and then shutdown? Is it also possible to shutdown after 30 mins of the command finishes?

Comment: What I meant was run the command `your-script && shutdown` instead of just `your-script`. You can also add a delay of 30 minutes by adding `sleep 30m &&` before `shutdown`.

Comment: ..or give minutes value as an argument in shutdown command, like `shutdown 30` or some specific time (in 24 hrs format), like `shutdown 16:00`. In first case, shutdown will occur after 30min and in second case at 4:00pm

Comment: Thanks! It is working fine now :)

Comment: @DanielPáscoa If you find this answer useful, please consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.